# Position image within text flow

Tags: floats

I am trying to have a picture positioned within the normal text flow. The problem is that it is positioned on the next page and different text is moved before it. I used `\begin{figure}[h]` using the `[h]` in the thought that it would be within the text flow. But it is not.

`\begin{figure}[h]
    \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth, center]{img/mypicture.png}
    \caption{Some caption text here}
    \label{myreference01}
\end{figure}`

Why is the picture outside of the text flow and not within? I thought using `[h]` does exactly that. What must I do to force the text flow?

Comment: the only purpose of the `figure` environment is to specify that the content is _not_ in the main text flow. You can just use `\includegraphics` directly.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The `\caption` and `\label` / `\ref` would not work anymore without `figure`.

Comment: you could use `\captionof` from the (one-line:-) `capt-of` package

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ok thanks for the link (the duplicate). With `float` and `[H]` the goal could be achieved.

Comment: but it is still the case that `[H]` (which I implemented originally:-) is logically contradictory as it takes `figure` which does nothing other than make a floating region, and specify it should not float. I feel bad every time anyone uses it, not that that ever stopped anyone:-)